# Adding a record to a table using VB.Net using SQLParameters

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

This is a very simple task of adding a record to a SQL table using vb.net, but I am struggling.

```
Dim query As String = String.Empty

query &= "INSERT INTO StudentInfo(StudentName,StudentPhone) VALUES(@param1,@param2)"

Using conn As New SqlConnection("csStudentDB")
    Using comm As New SqlCommand()
        With comm
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = query
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName", txtStudentName.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentPhone", txtStudentPhone.Text)
        End With
        Try
            conn.Open()
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

Web.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="csStudentDB" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I want to add a record to my table, but I get an error at the error is occuring at `Using conn As New SqlConnection(....."`

> "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 0."

Any solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 1):

In your INSERT statement you are using parameters @param1 and @param2. But in your code you are using @StudentName and @StudentPhone. They need to be the same.

Also, I have added the bit to retrieve the connection string.
For example:

```
Dim connString As String = String.Empty

    connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
.ConnectionStrings("csStudentDB").ConnectionString

    Dim query As String = String.Empty

query = "INSERT INTO StudentInfo(StudentName,StudentPhone) VALUES(@StudentName,@StudentPhone)"

Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
    Using comm As New SqlCommand()
        With comm
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = query
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName", txtStudentName.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentPhone", txtStudentPhone.Text)
        End With
        Try
            conn.Open()
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: ok, I am assuming csStudentDb is a variable holding your connection string. I have updated the answer.

Comment: csStudentDB is the name of the connectionstring in the web.config

Comment: see updated post. csStudentDB is from the web.config

Comment: now I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at "connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager....."

Comment: are you sure you got the whole line: connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("csStudentDB").ConnectionString

Answer (score 1):

if all else fails, try this:

```
Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=YourDBServerName;Initial Catalog=YourDBName;Integrated Security=True")
    Using comm As New SqlCommand()
        With comm
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = query
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName", txtStudentName.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentPhone", txtStudentPhone.Text)
        End With
        Try
            conn.Open()
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: thanks, though I would rather get the connection string from the web.config file

Comment: have a look at this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: Connection property is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    With comm
        .Connection = conn
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = query
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", txtStudentName.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", txtStudentPhone.Text)
    End With
```

since in your query

```
query &= "INSERT INTO StudentInfo(StudentName,StudentPhone) VALUES(@param1,@param2)"
```

you are specify the parameters as `@param1` and `@param2` so you must use the samme in `.Parameters.AddWithValue`